# My DNS settings constantly set itself to default

Tags: networking, dns, 15.10

I execute

`sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`

on terminal and when opened I modify the

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

to

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

but it resets to the unmodified version after reboot. How can I prevent this?

Version: 15.10 32-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you set the DNS nameservers in Network Manager. Right-click the NM icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select your relevant interface, either ethernet or wifi. Select IPv4 settings  and change the mode from Automatic (DHCP) to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only. Fill in your DNS nameservers, save and close.

Comment: Hey there. I tried setting it using GUI but it didn't work. I tried the method you described too but so far no luck. Using terminal to edit files manually turned out to work but is not permanent and that's why I focus on that.

Comment: What didn't work? What was the evidence? I don't doubt you; I am just gathering data. Did you try a reboot? Restarting NM? `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Weird. It worked this time. I went crazy over trying it for so many time and failing when I tried it through GUI. I can't see what is different now but it worked nonetheless. Thank you.

Comment: I'll take weird! Glad it's working.

Comment: Yeah so am I. I've ticked it. Even though the answer and question are not matching, it solved my problem and I believe the answer will be helpful to those who might've the same problem that I did.